# Initializing view elements at fragment android

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application I have some fragments. At their layouts I placed some elements, but I can't find how I may initialize the following elements. I also know about such way:

```
element = view.findViewById(R.id.element);
```

but I have some functions where I need to initialize the following elements:

```
public class Received extends Fragment {

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_received, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        received();
    }

    public void received() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://my_server/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        String access_token = "token";
        final APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
        mAPIService.getInMess("Bearer "+access_token,0, 1).enqueue(new Callback<ListOfMess>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Response<ListOfMess> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ListOfMess> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }


    /*private String getTokenFromShared(){
        return getSharedPreferences(Constants.SP_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Constants.SP_ACCESS_TOKEN, "");
    }*/

    public void fillList()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

I havу to initialize my elements at the function, I tried ***view.findviewbyid*** and only ***findViewbyId*** but nothing worked and the android studio couldn't find these elements. I hope that you will help me with the following problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Fragments you need to initialize your views in onCreateView method, just like that:

```
View element;    

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_observations_list, container, false);
    element = view.findViewById(R.id.element);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I know it, but if I initialize my view in onCreateView method, I won't find it at my other methods, so I decided to initialize these views at the following methods, and I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: You have access to "element' View from every method in this Fragment, what doesn't it mean that "you won't find it at my other methods"?

Comment: when I have initialized my view at onCreateView then Android Studio doesn't see any of initialized views.

Comment: Can you edit code in your question to include such an initialization and line where's problem with finding the view?

Comment: I looked through my question and you can see that I had inserted the code of my fragment and I'm trying to initialize my view at  public void received()